# How to store and work from a Postgresql database on an external hard drive?

Tags: postgresql, windows

I have installed PostgreSQL 13.1 on two computers, a laptop and desktop.

I created database using a Tablespace on a portable SSD drive under `F:\MyProject\DB\PG_13_202007201\20350`. So I expect all the database files to be in there somewhere.

I want to work on the database on the SSD drive which is fine on the laptop that created the database, but when I go to my desktop I can't figure out how to attach (SQL Server style) the existing database/tablespace and continue working on it.

Is there a way to work like this with Postgresql?

Comment: You cannot "attach (SQL Server style)" a Postgres database. You'll need to configure your Postgres cluster to look for the database files on the mounted path. See if [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/243253/how-to-move-old-data-to-cheap-hard-drive?rq=1) helps.

Comment: Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65013513/how-to-open-an-existing-postgresql-database-on-a-different-computer/65016189#65016189).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to create a new [cluster](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/creating-cluster.html) in your external drive. You can use [initdb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-initdb.html)
to create a new PostgreSQL database cluster.

Here is a sample command;

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin\initdb --pgdata="F:\MyProject\pgdata\13\main"
```

After that you even can register your new cluster as a new postgresql server service by using [pg_ctl](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-ctl.html) like the one below;

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin\pg_ctl register --pgdata="F:\MyProject\pgdata\13\main"
```